# Getting warning from unit test

Tags: python, unit-tests

I get a warning from this test but I don't know how to handle it. The warning is

`/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py:600: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name='/tmp/20170926_084744_545761.pdf'>
  testMethod()`

The code I'm testing (with Mako and Bottle) is:

```
  pdf.pdf_export(selected_date=selected_date, values=values, to_pdf_file=to_pdf_file)
            return static_file(to_pdf_file, root='/tmp', download=filename)
```

My test case looks as follows

```
 # Test is based on assumption of having the appropriate parameters for the expected output
    def testPDFexportByLogic(self):
        filter = ''
        sortby = '1'
        reverse1 = '1'
        reverse = True
        if reverse1 == '-1': reverse = False

        oncall_logic = OncallLogic(self.resources, view_type=OncallViewType.daily)
        oncall_logic.set_selections(selected_customer_id='417', listing_customer_ids='417',
                                    selected_date='20170925')
        pdf_file = oncall_logic.get_oncall_pdf_export_daily_events(self.resources, '417',
                                                                   '417', '20170925', filter=filter,
                                                                   sortby=int(sortby), reverse=reverse)

        filename = 'pdf-temp'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as w:
            w.write(pdf_file.body.read())
        self.assertIn("Sjukhus", str(self.convert_pdf_to_txt(filename)))
        os.remove(filename)
```

The above test succeeds to render the PDF and check the text, but I get a warning from running the test. Is the warning from the actual test or from running the code which is tested? Which file is it that I must close, if any?

I restructure the code and I still get the warning. I still get the ResourceWarning. I don't understand it because I only open one file and the warning is about the other file. Why???

```
def testPDFexportByLogic(self):

    filename = 'pdf-temp'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as w:
        oncall_logic = OncallLogic(self.resources, view_type=OncallViewType.daily)
        oncall_logic.set_selections(selected_customer_id='417', listing_customer_ids='417',
                                    selected_date='20170925')
        pdf_file = oncall_logic.get_oncall_pdf_export_daily_events(self.resources, '417',
                                                                   '417', '20170925')
        w.write(pdf_file.body.read())
        w.close()
        self.assertIn("Sjukhus", str(self.convert_pdf_to_txt(filename)))
```

These are my import statements in the test code:

```
import os
import io
import pdfminer

from controllers.oncall import oncall
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from business.logic.oncall.oncall_logic import OncallLogic
from business.resources.entities.gui.gui_settings import OncallViewType
```

The following is more code that is tested:

```
def pdf_export(self, selected_date, values, to_pdf_file):
    """
     @param selected_date: Date of the view to export
     @type selected_date: str
     @param values: Dict with values for the template the write on
     @type values: dict
     @param to_pdf_file: Name of the PDF file to write
     @type to_pdf_file: str
     """
    css = '/srv/http/python.dev/python-common/static_files/css/pdf-export-styles.css'
    pdfkit.from_string(render_template("oncall/dayview_pdf_export", values), '/tmp/' + to_pdf_file, css=css)
```

Comment: What library are you using to export to pdf? Could you show your import statements in the test and the code under test? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I updated the question with the additional details.

Comment: Thanks! I think the easiest way to approach the problem would be to find the source of warning by [marking warnings as errors and inspecting the traceback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208567/how-to-find-out-where-a-python-warning-is-from). Please post what you've got after you do so.

Comment: `Exception ignored in: <_io.FileIO name='/tmp/20170926_152918_365562.pdf' mode='rb' closefd=True>
ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name='/tmp/20170926_152918_365562.pdf'>` is the new trace but it probably doesn't help us much?

Comment: @alecxe I use `pdfkit` to generate the PDF

Comment: Okay, yeah. Could you try to manually pinpoint the problematic part by commenting out  parts of the test and seeing if warning is there or not? Also, btw, you can define `reverse` this way: `reverse = reverse1 != '-1'`.

Comment: @alecxe It says the problem is in `bottle.static_file` and that is not my code. It is the bottle framework which is generating the file. I looked in that function but there was nothing strange there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summing up what we had debugged and figured out:

- the problem comes from the `static_file()` function in the `bottle` library
- if we look at the source code of that `static_file()` function, we can find [this line](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py#L2910):

  ```
  body = '' if request.method == 'HEAD' else open(filename, 'rb')
  ```

  which uses the "unsafe" `open()` call without explicitly closing the file.

Bottle had a [similar problem](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/pull/611) in the other part of the framework before. Just reported this problem as a new issue:

- [ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader... in static_file()](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/issues/1000)

And, until it is fixed, you may ignore the warning since this is not coming from your code and is not an error.

Answer (score 3):

As per the explanation given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057942/python-unclosed-resource-is-it-safe-to-delete-the-file)

> This ResourceWarning means that you opened a file, used it, but then forgot to close the file. Python closes it for you when it notices that the file object is dead, but this only occurs after some unknown time has elapsed. Thus in recent versions, Python also prints a ResourceWarning when it does that. It is a way for you to quickly identify where the unclosed files are, and properly close them. It might be important on some platforms which cannot have more than N files opened at the same time (e.g. 1024). Also, specifically on Windows, you cannot do some operations with a file if it's still open (e.g. deleting it).

You should structure the code so that the work and conversion/assertion you're doing is inside the `with open(filename, 'wb') as w:` block. You can take a cue from how the code is structured [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44592843/python3-reportlab-image-resourcewarning-unclosed-file-io-bufferedreader-na).

Comment: I still get the ResourceWarning. I don't understand it because I only open one file and the warning is about the other file. Why???

Comment: I think your code , may be not the one's you've highlighted is accessing this other file and not able to close it. You need to debug it better.